# cocoa Expected specifier-qualifier-list before struct

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax, typedef

I read the other posted solutions to using structs and resolving the "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before struct" related errors, but those aren't working.  Is it different in Objective C?  Do I need to declare my struct somewhere else in the class?  It gives me the error on the line where I declare the typedef.  Here is how it looks right now:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString *name;

    typedef struct _point {
        uint32_t x;
        uint64_t y;
    } Point;

    Point a;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Put it outside of the interface:

```
typedef struct _point {
    uint32_t x;
    uint64_t y;
} Point; 

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    Point a;
}
@end
```